# Zooming to selected feature in QGIS?

Tags: pyqgis

While trying to read a layer from PostgreSQL, in order to select one polygon and zoom to this feature, I see the entire layer but not the selected feature.
I am using an unconventional way solve the problem - I am running the three lines I marked as comments in my example.

Can anyone offer me a better way?

I am working with Windows 10, QGIS 2.18.22, PostgreSQL 10.

This is my code that I am running in Python Consol Editor:

```
from qgis.core import *
from console import console

uri = QgsDataSourceURI()
uri.setConnection ("127.0.0.1", "5432", "DB_Layers", "postgres", "myPassword")

uri.setDataSource("public",  'blocks_lay', "wkb_geometry", "")

layer1 = QgsVectorLayer ( uri.uri(False), "blocks", "postgres")
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(layer1, True)

crs = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(2039)
iface.mapCanvas().mapSettings().setDestinationCrs(crs)

layer1.setCrs(crs)
expressionCur = 'block_num = 6018'

it = layer1.getFeatures(QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterExpression(expressionCur))
layer1.setSelectedFeatures ( [ f.id() for f in it ])

boxWin = layer1.boundingBoxOfSelected() 
# console.show_console()
# print 'aaaa'
# console.show_console()
iface.mapCanvas().setExtent(boxWin)

iface.mapCanvas().refresh()
```

Comment: use `iface.actionZoomToSelected().trigger()`

Comment: @Francisco Raga. Thanks. But it does not help. I got the same result

Comment: @Francisco Raga. Sorry,  my mistake - it's WORKS . I put your code in the last line of file and it did the work.

Comment: I'm glad,I put my comment as an answer?

Comment: @Francisco Raga . Hi. After additional check I discovered that iface.actionZoomToSelected().trigger()  works only if  I already have some layer in TOC. In my case - the layer is the first to be displayed and zoomed to selected feature . So my problem is not solved.

Comment: what!?but you ara loading a layer in TOC and after zoom to selected,right?

Comment: Update my answer

Comment: @Francisco. Yes. If I open a new layer in empty QGIS Desktop and make a zoom to the selected feature I see the layer in full extent(zoom to layer) - the ZOOM is not done (please see my example code).
But if before already there is other layer (not important which)  displayed in QGIS - the zoom of my layer is done.

Comment: mmm.is strange beacause I'm working in a empty QGIS Desktop

Comment: @FranciscoRaga Thanks. I also succeeded when I execute each line separately in Python Console. But it did not work when I ran it as a script in Python Console Editor or in my plugin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `iface.actionZoomToSelected().trigger()` in your code for zoom to selected feature in QGIS

*change the database data using your information*

**Code**

```
from qgis.core import *

uri = QgsDataSourceURI()
uri.setConnection ("localhost", "5432", "OSM", "postgres", "postgres")

uri.setDataSource("public",  'grassland', "geom", "")

layer1 = QgsVectorLayer ( uri.uri(), "grassland", "postgres")
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(layer1, True)

crs = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(4326)
iface.mapCanvas().mapSettings().setDestinationCrs(crs)

expressionCur = 'cat = 10'

it = layer1.getFeatures(QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterExpression(expressionCur))
layer1.setSelectedFeatures ( [ f.id() for f in it ])

iface.actionZoomToSelected().trigger()
```

[image]

**UPDATE**

You are right, to use it in the console you must use some signal, like for example

```
from qgis.core import *

def Zoom_filter():
    iface.mapCanvas().mapCanvasRefreshed.disconnect(Zoom_filter)
    expressionCur = 'cat = 10'
    for lyr in QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayers().values():
        if lyr.name() == "grassland":
            it = lyr.getFeatures(QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterExpression(expressionCur))
            lyr.setSelectedFeatures ( [ f.id() for f in it ])
            iface.actionZoomToSelected().trigger()
            break

uri = QgsDataSourceURI()
uri.setConnection ("localhost", "5432", "OSM", "postgres", "postgres")

uri.setDataSource("public",  'grassland', "geom", "")

layer1 = QgsVectorLayer ( uri.uri(), "grassland", "postgres")

crs = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(4326)
iface.mapCanvas().mapSettings().setDestinationCrs(crs)
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(layer1, True)
iface.mapCanvas().mapCanvasRefreshed.connect(Zoom_filter)
```

Comment: Thanks. I also succeeded when I execute each line separately in Python Console.
But it did not work when I ran it as a script in Python Console Editor or in my plugin.

Comment: your are right!Update again

Comment: Thanks,, the program does the zoom successfully, but only after the entire layer is displayed in full extention. And this I want to avoid because it is unnecessary and that continues 2 minutes

Answer (score 0):

These statements should work too:

```
canvas = qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas()
canvas.zoomToSelected(layer1)
layer1.triggerRepaint()
```

Comment: Hi, My problem is to make zoom to selected features in layer (that is first and the only layer in QGIS display) without to display in the beginning the layer in full extent. Francisco Raga already explained me how to make zoom, but in his way I still must display first the layer in full extent. Thanks

Comment: Why do you first need to zoom to layer - all features?

Comment: Hi,  Sorry I did not explain myself well. I'll try to fix it. I want open the first layer in QGIS and immediately zoom to selected feature according to parameters defined before it in plugin ( polygon number)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution - after drawing the layer, I use : `QApplication.processEvents()`

Here is explanation about it : https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#processEvents
So - the code must be like it:

```
from qgis.core import *
uri = QgsDataSourceURI()
uri.setConnection ("127.0.0.1", "5432", "DB_Layers", "postgres", "myPassword")
uri.setDataSource("public",  'blocks_lay', "wkb_geometry", "")
layer1 = QgsVectorLayer ( uri.uri(False), "blocks", "postgres")
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(layer1, True)
crs = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(2039)
iface.mapCanvas().mapSettings().setDestinationCrs(crs)
layer1.setCrs(crs)

QApplication.processEvents()

expressionCur = 'block_num = 6018'
it = layer1.getFeatures(QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterExpression(expressionCur))
layer1.setSelectedFeatures ( [ f.id() for f in it ])
boxWin = layer1.boundingBoxOfSelected() 
iface.mapCanvas().setExtent(boxWin)
iface.mapCanvas().refresh()
```